# How can we have nested structures in C?

Tags: c, struct

I have a header file for a json parser where I have nested structures, but the problem is even with the typedefs before the structures it throws incomplete type `t_value`, I know i was once able to do this in C++ with classes, but I can't manage to get it to work in C, here is the header:

```
#ifndef FT_JSON_H
# define FT_JSON_H

# include <stdint.h>
# include <stdbool.h>
# include <sys/types.h>

typedef enum e_value_type   t_value_type;
typedef enum e_number_type  t_number_type;
typedef struct s_value      t_value;
typedef struct s_member     t_member;
typedef struct s_object     t_object;
typedef struct s_number     t_number;

enum e_value_type {
    object,
    array,
    string,
    number,
    boolean,
    null_ptr
};

enum e_number_type {
    Int,
    Float
};

struct s_number {
    t_number_type   type;
    union {
        long    i;
        double  f;
    };
};

struct s_object {
    size_t      size;
    t_member    member[]; //we have a t_member here
};

struct s_member {
    char        *string;
    t_value     value; // we have a t_value here
};

struct s_value {
    t_value_type    type;
    union {
        t_object        object; // we have a t_object here
        t_value         *array;
        char            *string;
        bool            boolean;
        void            *null_ptr;
    };
};


#endif //FT_JSON_H
```

Comment: The definition of the nested structure has to be before the structure that uses it, not just the typedef.

Comment: @Barmar So how do we do if we have two structure that has an instance of the other inside them? like in this case, no matter the order in which I write my structs I still have the error message

Comment: If two struct types could contain each other, they would be infinitely large.

Comment: @luther: Not if each contains only the other.

Comment: Yes. A contains B, B contains A. So the nested B contains another A.

Comment: If you need circular nesting like this, you have to use pointers to structures, not nested structures.

Comment: @Barmar indeed !! pointers are the answer to everything

Comment: That's why it's called the [Fundamental Theorem of Software Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers are the answer.

```
struct s_member {
    char    *string;
    t_value *value; //Instead of `t_value value;`
}
```